# Transforming a looping factor variable into a sequence of numerics

Tags: r, variables, transform

I have a factor variable with 6 levels, which simplified looks like:

```
1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 6 6 6 1 1 1 2 2 2 2... 1 1 1 2 2...  (with n = 78)
```

Note, that each number is repeated mostly **but not always** three times.
I need to transform this variable into the following pattern:

```
1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 6 6 6 7 7 7 8 8 8 8...
```

where each repetition of the 6 levels continuous counting ascending.
Is there any way / any function that lets me do that?

Sorry for my bad description!

Comment: Hi Bjorn, are you able to write some code which generates example data?

Comment: If not, can you `dput()` part of your data?

Comment: Try `?sort`. It sorts any vector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have a numerical vector that represents your simplified version you posted. i.e. `x = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,1,1,2,2)`, you can use this:

```
library(dplyr)

cumsum(x != lag(x, default = 0))

# [1] 1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 5 5
```

which compares each value to its previous one and if they are different it adds 1 (starting from 1).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try `rle`, i.e.,

```
v <- rep(seq_along((v<-rle(x))$values),v$lengths)
```

**Example with dummy data**

```
x = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,5,6,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4)
```

then we can get

```
> v
 [1]  1  1  1  2  2  3  3  3  4  4  5  6  7  7  8  8  9  9
[19]  9 10 10
```

Answer (score 0):

In *base* you can use `diff` and `cumsum`.

```
c(1, cumsum(diff(x)!=0)+1)
# [1] 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 6 6 6 7 7 7 8 8 8 8
```

Data:

```
x <- c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,6,1,1,1,2,2,2,2)
```